# Start cron and another process in single docker container

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

I have a docker image that will start a foreground httpd process.  I also have some tasks that
I'd like to run as cron jobs via crontab.

Ideally I'd like to start httpd as a non root user, however, to also start cron, will require me to be root

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update 
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get dist-upgrade -yq \
    && apt-get install -y cron httpd

# Do a bunch of other setup.....

USER 1000

#START PROCESSES....
```

The problem as I see it is that I cannot start cron as root, keep that process running and also start httpd as a foreground process.

Is there some way to have both these processes started in one docker container?

Comment: Why do they have to be the same container?

Comment: What tasks are you scheduling? Perhaps there's [another way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to tackle the problem. Running cron in the same container as your main process is an anti-pattern.

Comment: I have a script i need to call regularly which retrieves some configuration from a webservice. 

@DavidMaze true, do not have to be in the same container, I guess I'm not experienced enough in docker to consider what is possible with multiple containers

Answer (score 0):

You can configure user used to run command in docker with something like

```
ENV     USER_NAME dev                                                       
RUN     echo "${USER_NAME} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/${USER_NAME} && \
        chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/${USER_NAME}

ARG     host_uid=1001                                                               
ARG     host_gid=1001                                                               
RUN     groupadd -g $host_gid $USER_NAME && useradd -g $host_gid -m -s /bin/bash -u $host_uid $USER_NAME
```

And build your image using

```
docker build --build-arg "host_uid=$(id -u)" --build-arg "host_gid=$(id -g)" -t <ur img> .
```

But why you can't run a bash script to execute the process in the background every  time?

Comment: Good point, I had not considered that option of a script

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by running main process with `sh`

```
CMD [ "sh", "-c", "crond && /app/my-server-binary"]
```

Main process (PID 1) `sh` is now the parent process of both `crond` and `my-server-binary`, so they can work insite a container at the same time, since `crond` automaticly backgrounds itself.

Separating processes to different users might be hard this way but maybe you could run `CMD` as user and use sudo for `crond` process?